# Last task runs before the container: Wrong order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

In SSIS of SQL Server 2008, I have a task ("Start") connected to a container that has to finish everything before turning to the last task ("End"). However, task "End" keeps running BEFORE my container is finished.

How do I make it wait until the container has finished?

I already tried setting the constraints on the arrows to "on completion" instead of "on success" to no avail.

See a screenshot of my package here:
[image]

Comment: All I can think about here is that it thinks that the task is complete once it sends the command. What if you added end inside the container and connect all three execute SQL tasks to it.

Comment: I bet you copied `Start` and pasted it there, then you changed its name to `End` edited it. Is that right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't copy and pasted anything and putting the end inside the container didn't work either. However, I found out that my package was just bugged and was executing things that I took out of the package long ago. Upon creating a completely new package and doing the exact same thing I had been doing for hours, everything suddenly worked. >____< Thank you for giving me pointers, though!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer: My package was bugged. It was executing things I took out of the package ages ago. Upon creating an entirely new package everything was solved!